# Unknown MS Compiler Version 1916 - I'm trying to run Python with Flask and getting this error

Tags: python, flask, cygwin, flask-sqlalchemy

I had opened the file cygwinccompiler.py and the thing is, the version 1916 isn't handled within that file.

I'm new programming with Python and Flask, and I'm stuck in this point since yesterday. I would like to know with some Windows user got the same problem and how did you guys solve it?

File: "c:\user**\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 85, in get_msvcr
raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s  " % msc_ver)
ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1916

I had installed 
Flask
Flask-Session
psycopg2
SQLAlchemy <-- but in this point, I'm getting an error as well after getting the MS Compiler error with the same message error.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Guys.
after 1 1/2 day working so hard to find the solution for my problem I got it from the SQLAlchemy documentation, on https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/intro.html#installation

We can set up an environment variable like the following:
DISABLE_SQLALCHEMY_CEXT=1

After this workaround, my environment worked!

Comment: In order to install the C SQLAlchemy extensions, you must have a C compiler tool chain installed in cygwin. To check, enter `gcc --version` at the cygwin bash prompt. If missing, install the latest "gcc-core" package. Also, be careful that you are not mixing cygwin and windows versions of python. Use `python -V` or `python3 -V` to make sure you have cygwin versions. And use `python3 -m pip -V` to guarantee you are using the correct version of "pip".